# how to write xaml code to a config file in c#wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Im using windows presentation framework i have ever wonder is that possible to write a Extensiple Application markup language(XAML) code in config file if possible give me some answers

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can write xml code in a config file if you want. You can then open the file and parse it using an xml parser.

Make sure you are declare `using System.Xml;`

You can then load the contents of the file like this

`XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath)`

Inside the xdoc you will have the complete DOM where you can go through each element.